# Catch block is taking time to start execution

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am automating one scenario like- Pass a string in to an edit box, If string is available in **DB** then choose the existing data from suggestion list. If not then click on **New** Button.
 So for that am trying like this.

```
Test_Tag.sendKeys("Test");
try {
    if(tags_Suggestion_list.isDisplayed()){
        tags_Suggestion_list.click();
        System.out.println("try");
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("catch");
    create_New_Tag.click();
    System.out.println("new");
    waitForElementToBeVisible(create_Tag_PopUp);
    save_Tag_Btn.click();
    System.out.println("catch done");
}
```

- if data is old then its running smoothly.
- If New data then its taking time(near about one min) to come catch block. and executing successfully.

So please help me here if any other approach is there to handle this type of scenario.

Comment: does it take a minute to print "catch" or to print "catch done", if answer is 2nd then       waitForElementToBeVisible     function is taking up time in catch section.

Comment: Its taking time to print `catch`.